# iOS CorePlot scatter plot crashes when i load it many times

Tags: ios, memory, core-plot, scatter-plot

I'm writing an app in which i'm trying to use a scatterplot.

The scatterplot itself is correctly made, I modify the values, properties etc. The problem is that if I load the hostingView, that contains the graph, more than 15-16 times iPad 2 has problems to allocate memory and app crashes.

First, I double checked the code searching errors but the problem is still there. I tried, in a second moment, to release the hostingView istance and load another one in order to try to "clean" the cache but nothing changed. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is refresh the plot data, there's no reason to release the hosting view and graph and build new ones. Just call `-reloadData` on the graph (or on individual plots that need to be updated) to clear the cache and load new plot data.

Use the static analyzer and Instruments to check for any memory leaks in your code. It sounds like the graph isn't being released along with the hosting view.